# Show android native datepicker in a webview

Tags: javascript, android, datepicker

HI every programming guru

I am building an android webview app based and I would like to pick some date with a datepicker. I found Mobi Pick but it is not compactible with my css so the output is very bad. I also don't want to use phonegap. I know it is possible to call android native datepicker from javascript when text input get focus. Could anybody show me some samples or links to tutorials to have it done please.
Thanks in advance.

My HTML code

```
    <form >
<span>
<input type="date" placeholder="Start Date : aaaa-mm-jj">
 </span>
    <span>
<input type="date" placeholder="End Date : aaaa-mm-jj" >
 </span>
 <input type="BUTTON" value="Filter" onClick="Filter()" />
<div class="clear"> </div>  
</form>
```

I want to display a native android datepicker on date field focus.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `input`'s type to `date`? (HTML5)

Comment: yes I have done it but nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

```
public void openDatePickerUI()
{ 
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

//updateDisplay();
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
        mDateSetListener,
        year, month, day);
dpd.show();
}
```

Place it in the Main Activity for WebView. Try this.

Comment: thank for your quickly response. I will try and get you feed back

Comment: Its very difficult to guess what issue you are facing. If you can provide the code, error with basic explanation  by editing your question. Then, anybody may suggest whats going wrong.